# Wsgi write to error.log in ascii. Need utf-8

Tags: apache2, uwsgi

Good day!
I have an apache and wsgi application. Everything works fine, but I can’t configure Apache so that the Cyrillic alphabet is written to the journal in its normal form, and not \ xd0 \ xa1 \ xd0.
The application works with strings normally, but if I give print(), nonsense is written to the log.

I tried all the options except the right one.
Py 3.6 Ubumtu 18 Apache 2.4

Comment: This may be relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/853430/utf-8-characters-in-apache-access-log